# navigate back to tabspage and give an active tab with

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-providers, ionic2-tabs

I am working on an application and I want to navigate back to the TabsPage and than the specific second tab of 4 tabs.

So what I tried based on other answers on stack is this:

```
    export class ModalPage {  
      public tab: Tabs;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private viewCtrl: ViewController, public params: NavParams) {
          this.tab = this.navCtrl.parent;
      }

  submit(score, comment){
    let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();

    if(currentIndex === this.allExercises.length - 1){

      this.tab.select(1);
    }
```

But this throws me this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null`

How can I navigate within that `if statement` to the TabsPage with the second tab as active? Maybe there is an other way of achieving this.

Comment: this is a modal?

Comment: Just a page which functions as a modal

Comment: @suraj why? Could you maybe help me out on this?

Comment: how are you opening this ModalPage ?

Comment: @SandeepSharma like this: 

` let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, { sliderParam: this.slides, allExercisesParam: this.allExercises });`
      `  modal.present();`

Comment: if you inserted TabsPage to the root then you could get Tabs ref by this.navCtrl._app._rootNav._children[0] . Reasoning is Model and Root component are being inserted into the ion-app at the same level. You can't use directly navCtrl of model to get the Tabs.

Comment: @SandeepSharma in my app.component.ts I set the rootPage like this: `
  rootPage:any = LoginPage; ` But this will not show up again when logged in.

Comment: Yes if later in the app you use  this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage), then replace this.navCtrl.parent; line of code with the above code and give a try.

Comment: @SandeepSharma could you provide me an aswer please?

Comment: in the code it says property `_app` does not exist on type `NavController`

Comment: but when i console.log this.navCtrl than i see it, I cant build my app because of this error any suggestions??